# Pass empty array to function, populate array and obtain values

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters

From my main method, I want to declare an array of doubles (but not initialize it) and pass that to a function. In that function, the array will be initialized with some values.
Now back in my main method, I want to read and display those values.

```
populateValues (double*& values) {

    values [0] = 100;
    values [1] = 200;
    values [2] = 300;

}


int main() {

    double values[3];
    populateValues(values);

    for (int i=0; i <3; i++) {
        std::cout << values[i] << std::endl; 
    }

}
```

However, when I compile the above, I get the error message:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘double*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘double*’
```

There is something wrong in how I am passing the parameter no doubt, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `populateValues (double* values)`

Comment: Try avoiding C style arrays. `std::array<double, 3>` and magically the problem is no more.

Comment: C++ errors can be a little opaque (mostly because so many things can be valid, that syntax error could be similar to all sorts of valid things.) You can pass the parameter by pointer (*), or reference (&) - but you can't use both at once, like this. You can use an STL array, as @n.m. notes - in which case I would suggest passing by reference (if you use neither, you'll get a local copy, and the values won't be passed back.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
void populateValues (double * values) {
    values [0] = 100;
    values [1] = 200;
    values [2] = 300;
}

int main() {
    double values[3];
    populateValues(values);
    for (int i=0; i <3; i++) {
        std::cout << values[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with `double values[3];`, values is of type `double[3]` which might decay to `double*`.

expecting `double*&` require a true lvalue of type `double*`. And temporary cannot be bound to **no**-const reference

You might change to

- `void populateValues(double (&values)[3])`
- `void populateValues(double* values)`
- `void populateValues(double*const &values)` temporary can be bound to **const** ref.